# Using ViewModel to fetch data from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I have 3 classes for rules,requests,executions, and approvers.

I want to combine these three tables into a viewModel so that I can fetch Requestid, description,approvers and execution status in one single view.
Here is my first crude try which seems to work but I feel this is very incorrect way of creating a ViewModel. Please suggest a better approach.

```
public class Rules
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int RulesId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string RulesDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int ApprovalLevels { get; set; } //if 0 then auto approved.
    [Required]
    public virtual string Requestor { get; set; }
}

public class Requests
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int RequestsId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime RequestTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual bool isCompleted { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int RulesId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ExecutionStatus
{   
    [Required]
    public virtual int ExecutionStatusId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int RequestId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int CurrentApproverLevel { get; set; } 
    [Required]
    public virtual string ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
}
public class Approvals
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int ApprovalsId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int RulesId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual int ApproverLevel { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string ApproverName { get; set; }
}



public class RequestExecutionViewModel
{
    private RequestsContext db = new RequestsContext();
    public RequestExecutionViewModel(string username) 
    {
          this.Request = db.Requests.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(username)).First();
          //aa = db.Approvals.Where(a => a.RulesId.Equals(Request.RulesId));
          this.Approvals = (List<Approvals>) db.Approvals.Where(a => a.RulesId.Equals(Request.RulesId)).ToList();
          this.ExecutionStatus = (List<ExecutionStatus>)db.ExecutionStatus.Where(a => a.RequestId.Equals(Request.RequestsId)).ToList();
    }

    [Required]
    public virtual int RequestExecutionViewModelId { get; set; }
    public Requests Request   {get;set;}
    public List<Approvals> Approvals { get; set; }
    public List<ExecutionStatus> ExecutionStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Doing the database query inside model seems wrong to me. There should be a better way of doing things.

Comment: What do you feel is incorrect about it?  (Not commenting on it one way or the other, but it might be easier to give you a tip if we knew what you didn't like about it and wanted to change)

Comment: the composition is fairly good, however, you shouldn't have `private RequestsContext db = new RequestsContext();` and `RequestExecutionViewModel()` 
 included in the viewmodel. also, you might want to use `IList<>` rather than `List<>`

Comment: thanks jim. This is my worry too.Being a noob I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the composition is fairly good, however, you shouldn't have `private RequestsContext db = new RequestsContext();` and `RequestExecutionViewModel()` included in the viewmodel. also, you might want to use `IList<>` rather than `List<>`.

your db access should be performed in the service layer or the controller action and should probably be injected via some IOC container.

just my 2 cents

Comment: My answer is basically the same thing, this is most likely the way to go, the main problem with sometimes doing queries in ViewModels and sometimes doing it in controller actions is inconsistency.  If you did ever have to use that view model again with the same query it would beg the question of why you weren't just using the same action.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would do your model building in your **Controller Action**, not in the ViewModel code itself.  Boilerplate mapping code though could be useful in the ViewModel, but the querying of the database I don't think should be in there.

Not all pages will have ViewModels necessarily, and it would lead to DB queries scattered around if some do queries in the controller while some do it in the ViewModel.

Comment: yes Paul surprisingly all answers I have seen are addressing some aspect of ViewModel which is great for me. Sadly stackoverflow do not allow marking more than one good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this seems to be mostly fine. As far as I understand, a ViewModel should be used to provide just enough data from the Model(s) to your View, which yours does.

The only other thing I could suggest is maybe using the [Repository pattern](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) instead of directly using a `RequestsContext` so you could do unit testing better.